# Getting permission error on Firebase storage in Android?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

So I upload a file to firebase storage using this code snippet:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference parentReference = storage.getReference();
    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH));
    StorageReference childReference = parentReference.child("kas_data");
    UploadTask uploadTask = childReference.putFile(file);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            //
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            //
        }
    });
```

The upload takes place successfully. Checking the firebase console I see the file is uploaded successfully. Now I want to download it using the following code snippet:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference parentReference = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference childReference = parentReference.child("kas_data");
        File localFile = new File(PATH);
        childReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) { 
                //
            }
        });
```

But I get the following error message:

```
com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.
```

While I'm using this rule at Firebase Storage Rules section:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write;
    }
}
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Glide to download images just add:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
```

To your app build.gradle then

```
StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            final StorageReference imgRef = mStorageRef.child("Imagesfolder/"+"Imagename"+"");
            GlideApp.with(showProducts.this)
                    .load(imgRef)
                    .into(imageview);
```

This will download the image into an imageview!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not even sure how your upload task succeeded. You need to add a condition to the rules:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if true;
    //Or whatever condition you want to allow/disallow uploading and downloading
}
```

Comment: According to Firebase docs, if no condition is specified, the rule evaluates to true. like `allow read;` https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#understand_rules  @Amin